# Message Box in Adobe Air

Tags: flash, air, messagebox

Is their a built-in way to show a message box in adobe air.

I'm using air with the Flash IDE BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Alert.html#show()).

Answer (score 0):

I previously answered this question that there was no built-in solution.

But today i found a good solution and started to use it in my projects. It is a class made by Ben Foster. You should save the class with NativeAlert name, import it in your projects and start using in a simple way like this:

```
nativeAlert.alert("Hello there!");
```

Here is the link of the solution : http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2012/03/simple-way-to-get-native-alerts-with-adobe-air/